# exchange axis of an "ezplot"

Tags: matlab

how can i change the horizontal and vertical axis of an ezplot of a symbolic equation?

for example an implicit equation of lambda & beta.
how MATLAB can understand what i want to be for x axis and what for y axis??

---

but i have a main expression of beta not a function and is so long. because it is made of some parameters that they themselves are made of some expressions too.
how can i convert it to a function? i mean, can i use the name of the main expression to make a function?

for example if:
n1,n2,m,a=const.
u=sqrt(n2-beta^2);    w=sqrt(beta^2-n1);
a=tan(u)/w+tanh(w)/u; b=tanh(u)/w;
f=(a+b)*cos(a*u+m*pi)+a-b*sin(a*u+m*pi);  is the main expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function handle, and flip the order (x,y) vs (y,x):

```
figure(1), ezplot( @(x,y) sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 - 1), [-2 2 -4 4] )
figure(2), ezplot( @(y,x) sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 - 1), [-2 2 -4 4] )
```

---

Let me give you another easier solution. Just plot your your function the usual way, then use:

```
view([90 -90])
```

to rotate the axes (x-axis becomes y-axis and vice versa)